# SQL Server gets the name of table with the suffix name until the day before yesterday

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use this sql to get the name of table with the suffix name until the day before yesterday:

```
select name from sys.objects where type='u'
and name like '%T_MYDATE_%'  
and name not like 'T_MYDATE_'+CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE()-1, 112)   
and name not like 'T_MYDATE_'+CONVERT(varchar(100), GETDATE(), 112)
```

The output likes this:

```
name
---------------
……
T_MYDATE_20181120
T_MYDATE_20181121
T_MYDATE_20181122
T_MYDATE_20181123
T_MYDATE_20181124
T_MYDATE_20181125
```

I think the sql is not good,is there a better way to do it?

Comment: why are you creating table by date ?

Comment: Let's start thinking about the code we write. What does style 112 generate for converting a date? A string in the format YYYYMMDD. So why do you convert it as varchar(100)? It both fixed in width and much smaller in width. Next, you search for values that contain T_MYDATE_ yet your exclude values that start with T_MYDATE. Inconsistent logic is not a good attribute for a developer. Lastly, never assume rows are ordered if the statement that generated it has no order by clause. Will these things matter? Can't say. Do you feel lucky? You are probably depending on it.

Comment: And underscore is a wildcard for like. You are not really matching a specific pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, but here is just another option

```
 ...
 Where type='u'
   and name like '%T_MYDATE_%'  
   and right(Name,8)<convert(varchar(8),GetDate()-1,112)
```

Comment: Sorry,sir,I use sqlserver2008.
I think I should use `right(name,8)<convert(varchar(100),GetDate()-1,112)`

Comment: @Rhaegal Just saw that.  Removed the try_convert

Comment: @Rhaegal Without the try_convert() you run the risk of throwing an error

Comment: @Rhaegal Updated to a string comparison